# Under what conditions do fixed-point iterations by an affine transformation converge?

Tags: linear-algebra, convergence-divergence, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations, fixed-point-theorems

Under what conditions do iterations by $\mathbf{x}_{new}=A\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{b}$ converge (to $(I-A)^{-1}\mathbf{b}$)?

Would it be correct to say that convergence is guaranteed if all the eigenvalues of $A$ have magnitude under 1.0?

---

Secondly, if we suppose that the fixed-point iterations do not converge, and that the diagonal entries of $A$ are all zero, how can we modify the update rule to make the iterations converge (still to $(I-A)^{-1}\mathbf{b}$)?

I imagine iterating instead with $\mathbf{x}_{new}=\frac{1}{s}(A\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{b})+(1-\frac{1}{s})\mathbf{x}=\frac{1}{s}((A-(1-s)I)\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{b})$ but I don't know whether to relate $s$ to the largest eigenvalue of $A$ or to something else, to guarantee convergence.

Comment: Convergence is guaranteed if all the *singular* values are less than $1$; this follows e.g. from the Banach fixed point theorem or just by a direct calculation. I don't know what you mean by "make them converge"; of course you can make it converge by setting $A = b = 0$... do you mean modify it so that it converges but to the same point?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yes. To "make it converge" by modifying the update rule to a dampened version of the original rule. I'm trying to understand how to select an appropriate constant $s$.

Comment: Suppose $A$ is diagonal with diagonal entries $2, 0$. Then the eigenvalues of your proposed iteration are $1 + \frac{1}{s}$ and $1 - \frac{1}{s}$(and the singular values are the absolute values of these). Then there's no value of $s$ such that these both have absolute value less than $1$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan If $A$'s diagonal is known to be all zero would that take care of it or could some similar issue still exist?

Comment: No, the same issue occurs if $A$ has eigenvalues $0$ and $2$ (the largest eigenvalue is a lower bound on the largest singular value).